# angular2 service passing response to component

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm trying to separate the `http` request from my component and putting it in a service, how can I pass the response I get from the request to my action in my component?

Like in angular 1 you can do something like the code below in the controller, and do the `http` request in a service.

```
var getGenreList = function() {
            coreGenreService.getGenreList(vm.id)
                .then(function(response) {
                     console.log(vm.name);
                });
        }
```

I tried sort of applying the same logic however I'm not sure how I can pass the response to my controller.

Service:

```
getUser(){
        this.http.get('http://../api/User?email='+this.customerEmail)
            .map(response => response.text())
            .subscribe(data => {
                if (data) {
                    var userObj = JSON.parse(data);
                    this.UserEmail = userObj.EmailAddress;
                }
        });
    }
```

I can see that this is getting the json objs but when I do a search I don't see any values in the object, I'm guessing because its not being passed in the `searchUser()`

```
searchUser() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    if(!this._searchService.getUser()){ 
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        }, 500)
    }
}
```

Html input structure:

```
<input type="text" name="UserEmail" [(ngModel)]="customerEmail" placeholder="Search customer email"> <br>
<button (click)="UserCustomer()" class="omni-btn search-btn float-shadow">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to refactor your service this way:

```
getUser(customerEmail: string): Observable<string>{
    return this.http.get(`http://../api/User?email=${customerEmail}`)
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```

In your component, you can call the service like this:

```
searchUser() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this._searchService.getUser(this.customerEmail)
    .subscribe(user => { 
      this.isLoading = false;

      // To use for data binding in the component
      this.user = user;

      console.log('user = ', user);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the .subscribe is saying does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: @nCore Define the return type explicitly `getUser(): Observable<string>{...}`

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy where do I inject that? its saying IObservable cannot find name.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier where can I console.log the response for now? I wanna see if its returning the right objs.

Comment: @nCore you can use `console.log` but within the `map` or `subscribe` callback... I updated my answer.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Thanks, but I'm getting a null. The idea is to just search for the user's email but return all the user information not just their email. Where is the data binding (ngModel) is happening?

Comment: @nCore I updated my answer accordingly. Regarding data binding, you can use the `user` object...